# Clustering rows with matching element values in any column

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to label and cluster rows where they link in matching values under any column.

| row | id1 | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b | c |
| 1 | a | d | f |
| 2 | d | g | h |
| 3 | b | g | l |
| 4 | c | e | c |

In the above example, we can see that rows 0 and 1 match within id1 with 'a'. But 0 and 4 also match within id3 with 'c'. So rows 0, 1, and 4 are grouped under one cluster. 2 and 3 match under id2, so they are grouped in another separate cluster. They will be labelled with `cluster_id`.

How can I do this automatically with pandas no matter how many rows and additional id columns `n`? We can assume no duplicate rows, and it needs to work for at least a million records.

Comment: What happens if you have a 5 row that matches with 2 and 3, and with 4? For example [c, g, c]? Any thoughts on how to do this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DaniMesejo i guess then you would have 1 cluster. This is a `networkx` problem.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, is a networkx problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, this is a `networkx` problem. First, we need to build the adjacent matrix:

```
import networkx as nx

s = df.filter(like='id').values
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix((s == s[:,None]).any(axis=-1))

cluster = dict(enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)))
# {0: {0, 1, 4}, 1: {2, 3}}
```

Note that we use broadcasting to construct adjacent matrix, so this approach might not work for many many rows. I'd say it works fine for around `5k rows x 10 ids` (about 250M when broadcasing)

Also note that the nodes inside each cluster are representing the **range index** of the dataframe, not the values in `row` columns. So if you want to know the node names in, say cluster `0`, you need:

```
df['row'].iloc[list(cluster[0])]
```

---

Update: We can use `melt` and `merge` to build the adjacency, which might be better for long dataframe:

```
s = df.melt('row')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(s.merge(s, on=['value','variable']), 
                            source='row_x', 
                            target='row_y')
```

This approach would be better since the node names are taken from the values in column `row` rather than the indexing.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, but with some extra work. See updated answer.

Comment: I need this to work for over 1 million records, and most likely 5 ids max. So this solution won't work for this?

Comment: @VinhNguyen nope, pair-wise comparison on `1M` rows are not the scale for Pandas on PC. You might want to look at distributed computing.